# Form post values

Tags: forms

Now i had multi form in my template,this form using POST method and each form contains input hidden.Then how can I get this hidden value in next template (page)?

First page code

```
<form name="input" action="r_rss_openOneNews_Test" method="post">
<label for="urlLabel">{rss_title}</label>
<input type="submit" value="More...">
<input type="hidden" name="urlHidden" value="{rss_link}">           
</form>
```

How can i get `urlHidden` value in `r_rss_openOneNews_Test` page?

Thanks,

Comment: Duplicate of [Sending paramters in url](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14548/sending-paramters-in-url) & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335398/passing-url-paramaters

Comment: This isn't an EE specific question as written so I'm closing it. It's more appropriate for the StackOverflow site. Please edit the question to include more EE specific details and I'll reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mo’ Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) for the same.

Comment: Kindly,Can you send me code which I write in first page and code I write in second page using Mo’ Variables plugin

Thanks