# Sending paramters in url

Tags: url, querystring

Any idea about How can I send paramaters in url in expression tags and get values of this paramaters in next page

In first template I wrote this code

```
<a href ='r_rss/openOneNews?url={rss_link}'>{rss_title}</a>
```

Q:How can I get `url` paramater value in next page which is `openOneNews` to can use as the following in next page `<iframe src = 'url' />`

Thanks

Comment: Please, improve your answer and tell us which EECMS version you're using.

Comment: I use EE version 2.5

Comment: Ahmed - please don't cross-post the same question: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14546/form-post-values & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335398/passing-url-paramaters

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an add-on for this. [Mo’ Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) is a good option.

```
{get:url}
```

Maybe you should rename your variable. "url" is too common and it can create some conflicts.

Comment: Please, mark the answer as the right one.